# Java persistence .jar file not running

Tags: java, netbeans, persistence

I have built a simple application which connects database made in derby(Netbeans) which binds with a jTable, using java persistence, entity manager. The problem is that when i run the .jar file on some other system it does not execute. Can anyone tell me why does it happen?

Error when running it on some other system:

```
C:\>java -jar persist.jar
[EL Info]: 2013-01-08 17:06:45.715--ServerSession(4597467)--EclipseLink, version
: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
[EL Severe]: 2013-01-08 17:06:48.24--ServerSession(4597467)--Exception [EclipseL
ink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.p
ersistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.Connec
tException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Conn
ection refused: connect.
Error Code: 40000
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: E
xception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r104
61): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.Connec
tException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Conn
ection refused: connect.
Error Code: 40000
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(En
tityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.get
DatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.cre
ateEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createE
ntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createE
ntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at persist.NewJFrame.initComponents(NewJFrame.java:30)
    at persist.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:17)
    at persist.NewJFrame$1.run(NewJFrame.java:101)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v2
0111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.Connec
tException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Conn
ection refused: connect.
Error Code: 40000
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(Dat
abaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(Dat
abaseException.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConn
ector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(
DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAn
dDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.log
in(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(En
tityManagerSetupImpl.java:488)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectExceptio
n : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection re
fused: connect.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unkn
own Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Sourc
e)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConn
ector.java:98)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: java.net.ConnectExcep
tion : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection
refused: connect.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl40.newNetConne
ction(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: What error does it give you

Comment: It shows no error. When i double click on the jar file nothing happens.

Comment: run it on command line with java -jar and you will see the error

Comment: ok i'll try it and then tell u

Comment: Error: Could not find main class persist.jar

Comment: You created your own `jar` that uses `persist.jar` as it's dependency, right?

Comment: yes its jFrame consisting of a jTable connected to derby database.

Comment: Unzip the Jar and check the Main-Class is defined in the Manifest.mf file

Comment: My apologies, i am getting the following error, i edited it in the question.

Comment: How does other system knows where your DB is ? check my answer

Comment: no it dosent. i'll try it out and let u know.

Comment: Yes, i have resolved the problem. I just needed to place my db in the other system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100042/using-task-scheduler-for-running-java-jar-from-batch-file/14100196#14100196). Seems like a similar problem (namely, the dependency jar(s) are probably not on the `classpath`).

**EDIT**
Since you posted the stack trace, it's pretty obvious now that you have some DB connection problems:

```
java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with messageConnection refused: connect.
```

Did you check if the database is up & running properly on that other system?

Comment: Actually i have no idea how do i set up the database on the other system.

Comment: So, as it seems, you don't have the database at all on that other system, there's your answer :) Frankly, you didn't even mention what that "other" system is, what OS and stuff, but you can google for "how to install DB derby on xxx"

Comment: Alright, it means that i need to install Derby on the 'other ' system (apart from my development pc), make the database  and then try to run the application, right?

Comment: Of course. If you have the DB only locally (for development purposes), you certainly need to install it on the 'other' system and create all the tables (and export/import data, if needed), but that's a whole other story, unrelated to your original question.

Comment: i suppose the problem is with my DB!

Comment: No i'm away from my project fro some time but when i'll do it i'll defiantly post here.

Comment: I have resolved the problem. It was the database folder that had to be copied on the other system, opening the connection and then running the jar file. I worked really fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the database url in your persistence.xml

```
<properties>
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sa"/>
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
                         value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://??:1527/??"/>
</properties>
```

Netbeans assigns default location when you are running app inside netbeans where your db is created. I suggest you to pass url as parameter for creating entity manager factory or have it in a property file and load it.

```
java -jar project.jar persistence.properties
```

Comment: Thanks, i solved it. I just needed to place the database folder in my other system.